# Cannot rebase git, merge and Gerrit

Tags: git, merge, gerrit, rebase, cherry-pick

I have done something really weird. And I don't know what to do know.

I am working with Gerrit, and it just showed me that it cannot merge because of a conflict, but there were no conflicts, but instead I guess it was because of detached `HEAD`

And I started to do really random thing, firstly I `cherry-picked` 3 commits into one, and than I got the master branch again detached, that I tried to rebase, but got a merge conflict, so finally I got the following log

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N6Tt.jpg

This is because I don't understand the difference between `merge` and `rebase`

Could you please help me to fix the history (into one straight line) and answer the question :

What is the difference between `merge` and `rebase` if by default git uses `fast-forward` so the result looks exactly the same as rebase does. And in my case I couldn't make the rebase because of merge conflicts. So what is the purpose of `rebase` than ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) is different from [merge](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#_basic_merging) because git uses `fast-forward` only if it can. E.g.: you create a new branch from `master`, you commit to your new branch, you don't commit to `master`, and then you want to `merge` your changes back to master: git will think this is the same as if you'd have just committed to `master` anyway. And it'll think the same if you'd use `rebase` in this situation.

The real fun begins when you have changes on both branches and git can't use fast-forward: then `merge` will create a new commit for which the parents will be your last commits on both of your branches, and `rebase` will try to move the base of your branch that you're trying to rebase to the head of your other branch.

So, to "fix" your history (into one straight line), you need to undo your merge (labeled as head) and you need to rebase your `Rebasing` branch to your `master` branch

```
git checkout Rebasing
git rebase master
```

You'll still have conflicts, that you need to resolve and continue with

```
git rebase --continue
```

as many times as necessary.